# How to execute condition based on XCODE version using conditional compilation in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, conditional-compilation

I need to execute some conditions based on the XCODE version. Is it possible to achieve using conditional compilation symbols?

for example,

```
            this.datePicker = new UIDatePicker();
            this.datePicker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;
#if (XCODE version)
            //This code should be executed for XCODE 12 and above
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0))
            {
                this.datePicker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels;
            }
#endif
```

I need these conditions should be enabled for XCODE 12 and above. For lower XCODE versions the conditions should be disabled.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: @SushiHangover, Thank you for your reply. I need a conditional compilation symbol based on Xcode to decide the execution at compile time. How can I disable the condition to be compiled in a lower Xcode machine?

Comment: There are no pre-defined conditions in Xamarin.iOS for that, you would need to assign one yourself